# Confusing hibernate behaviour using spring data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I just hit a really strange case which I can't explain to myself. I have have the following scenario:

Hibernate version: 5.4.9

Spring data version: 2.2.3

So the following method is wrapped in a transaction and it only saves the entity

```
   @Transactional
   public Bookmark create(Entity entity) {
     return repository.save(entity);
   }
```

Here I registered a PostInsertEventListener. Based on some logic it uses the same repository to query the underlying table. I removed the logic in order to make the example more readable.

```
@Component
public class EntityListener implements PostInsertEventListener {

  @Autowired
  private EntityRepository repository;

  @Autowired
  private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    final EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImplementor) entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class)).getServiceRegistry()
        .getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
    registry.appendListeners(EventType.POST_INSERT, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
    if (event.getEntity() instanceof Entity) {
      repository.findByFieldOneAndFieldTwoIsNotNull(event.getEntity().fieldOne());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister persister) {
    return false;
  }

}
```

So when I invoke the `create(Entity entity)` method the `onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event)` is triggered(as expected) but when this line is invoked `repository.findByFieldOneAndFieldTwoIsNotNull(event.getEntity().fieldOne());`
 then another insert is executed and the `onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event)` is triggered again. And of course at some point this leads to StackOverflowException.

Can someone come up with an idea why another insert is executed when I'm reading data using findBy query?

Answer (score 0):

So i have a progress on that issue. When I execute `repository.findByFieldOneAndFieldTwoIsNotNull(event.getEntity().fieldOne());` in a new separate transaction then everything is fine. So it seems that executing queries in the entity listener in the same transaction that the insert was executed on is leading to an infinite recursion which leads to a StackOverflowException. But I can't figure it out why is this happening.